# MInecraft command blocks to track days on a server

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-java-edition-server

I'm trying to make a command block setup to keep track of each day that passes on my server so that I can trigger "random" events at different intervals. I thought i had it figured out by using this guide:

[image]

But after making it, I noticed it was scoring each player separately. I had 10 days passed, my friend joined and I noticed he had 2 days passed when I glanced at the log. I need ONE global counter for days across the server.

Can someone please explain how to do this step by step?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you probably have a command along this line `/scoreboard players add NAME @a 1` or something. This adds a count to everyone, but what you need is a global one not dependent on players.

And here it is!
Simply summon an armor stand with a name or something and set the `@a` to `@e[type=armor_stand,name=NAME]`